# How can I modify my js in order to make it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is coming from here :
https://www.superhi.com/video/how-to-make-reactive-type-as-seen-on-the-airbnb-cereal-site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');

    #box {
        font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 80px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #grid-items {
         width: 1200px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: 100px;
    }

    .letter {
        font-weight: 100;
        transform: scale(0.2);
        transition: transform 0.75s;
    }
</style>

    <section id="box">  
        <section id="grid-items">
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
          <div class="letter">s</div>
          <div class="letter">u</div>
          <div class="letter">p</div>
          <div class="letter">e</div>
          <div class="letter">r</div>
          <div class="letter">h</div>
          <div class="letter">i</div>
        </section>
        </section>

    <script>
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
      const x = event.pageX;
      const y = event.pageY;

        document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
        const dx = (div.offsetLeft + 50) - x;
        const dy = (div.offsetTop + 50) - y;
        const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        const score = Math.exp(dist * -0.003);

        div.style.transform = "scale(" + score + ")";
        div.style.fontWeight = 100 + (100 * Math.floor(8 * score));
        });

    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Everything is working just fine. But when I try to include it in wordpress, the section simply disappears. The issue is probably that I have other divs in my page. So I would like to modify the js in order to target all the styled div (with the class) instead of the simple div selector. But I don't know how I can achieve that ;(

Thanks for your precious help.

Edit : Thanks for your help guys. The issue is not to target the proper div with the good class. I've already tried to fix this during hours before posting my noob question ;(

I think the most important problem is that the demo is working on a single page. What I'm trying to do is to put it in section that is to far away from the top of the document... So pageY is not the good function to use in that case (it returns numbers that are to big to make the code work properly). What I need now (I guess), is modifying this two lines in order to return the mouse position depending on the grid section not on the document :

const x = event.pageX;
const y = event.pageY;

And once again, I don't know how I can do it... I guess Offset is the way to go but I don't know how...

Edit 2 : 
I fixed the issue using event.clientX and event.clientY.
Thanks four your precious help.

```
<script>

    document.getElementById("grid-items").addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
        const x = event.clientX;
        const y = event.clientY;

    document.querySelectorAll("#grid-items > div.letter").forEach(div => {
        const dx = (div.offsetLeft + 50) - x;
        const dy = (div.offsetTop + 50) - y;
        const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        const score = Math.exp(dist * -0.003);

        div.style.transform = "scale(" + score + ")";
        div.style.fontWeight = 100 + (100 * Math.floor(8 * score));
    });
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("div");` <-- so change it to target the divs. Add the class

Comment: Yup - you could use: `document.getElementsByClassName("letter").forEach(div => {`

Answer (score 0):

Try

`document.querySelectorAll("#grid-items > .letter").forEach(div => {`

instead of your current `div` selector.

The above will select all the divs with the class name `letter` that are direct children of `#grid-items` div.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling 'mousemove' event on section tag itself.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  const x = event.pageX;
  const y = event.pageY;
  //document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach(div => {
  document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0].querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {

    const dx = (div.offsetLeft + 50) - x
    const dy = (div.offsetTop + 50) - y
    const dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

    const score = Math.exp(dist * -0.003)

    div.style.transform = "scale(" + score + ")"
    div.style.fontWeight = 100 + (100 * Math.floor(8 * score))
  })
})
```